# getRawX() and getRawY() not Correct Value in PinterestView Library Android

Tags: android, gesture

I have Problem with this Library > https://github.com/brucetoo/PinterestView. This Library is make Menu Action Like Pinterest When Press Long on some View.
Like this:
[image]

**The problem** :
if I remove **Toolbar View**, the position the menu action is not Correct like this :

[image]

And I just think, this problem is **mCenterX**  and **mCenterY**  in **[PinterestView.Class](https://github.com/brucetoo/PinterestView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/brucetoo/pinterestview/PinterestView.java)** :

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Long press detected");
            mCenterX = e.getRawX() - mChildSize / 3;
            mCenterY = e.getRawY() - mChildSize / 3;
            confirmDegreeRangeByCenter(mCenterX, mCenterY);
            PinterestView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(mPinMenuClickListener!=null) {
                mPinMenuClickListener.onShow();
            }
            switchState(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Single Click");
            if (mPinMenuClickListener != null) {
                mPinMenuClickListener.onPreViewClick();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But I don't know how to fix. So how to solve it ? thanks